# How to tether Verizon Hotspot to Linksys router?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, home-networking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I bridge a Verizon mobile hotspot modem/router to a Linksys router?](https://superuser.com/questions/384664/how-can-i-bridge-a-verizon-mobile-hotspot-modem-router-to-a-linksys-router)

I have a Verizon MiFi 4620L and I want to connect it via USB Tether to my Linksys E4200 Router. Seems like the Linksys firmware can only handle USB storage devices and isn't really setup to support network devices connected to the USB port.

I've heard of flashing custom firmware to do this, but I wanted to keep this simple. I have Verizon for internet service, but I need to connect that MiFi device to my router to get a greater Wi-Fi range through the house. I figure this is the best way to do it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you can do this without using a 3rd party firmware.  You need to configure your router as a wifi relay/extender and the included firmware won't allow that. Here is the information on ddwrt for your router. http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Linksys_E4200