# Want a single network not two

Tags: networking, router, hotspot

I have a verizon Hotspot for internet. I have a network drive on a router. I want to run backups to the network drive. Problem is needing to switch networks so I can't schedule backups. My router can be an access point but I can't make it an access point on the Verizon Network. Similar questions have been asked/answered but nothing seems to quite fit my issue.

Help? Is there anyway to get my router/network drive on the same network as the HotSpot or a  way to automatically switch networks when the backup is scheduled to run?

Comment: Hello Becca, welcome to SU.  Can you [edit] and explain a little more about what is preventing you using the AP in conjunction with the verizon hotspot?

Answer (score 0):

we could help better with more specific information about the hardware involved, but here is the general idea.

You want to connect your router to the hotspot with the router in bridge mode. That means that your router will be extending an existing network and not creating one itself. Have a look [here](http://www.ehow.com/how_2308667_use-router-as-bridge.html), [here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-turn-an-old-router-into-a-wireless-bridge/) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/384664/how-can-i-bridge-a-verizon-mobile-hotspot-modem-router-to-a-linksys-router).