# Use 2 different internet connections for 2 different programms

Tags: networking, internet

I have 2 different internet connections.

The first one is my usual home internet connection with a mediocre but stable speed.

The second one is a tethered connection from my phone which is very fast but not as stable.

My plan is to livestream a video game via my home connection, but since it is not the fastest I am unable to game smoothly and stream at the same time. Only streaming tho is perfectly fine.

Thats why I only want to use this connection for the livestream.

As far as all other traffic goes (Spotify, Different Games, Web browsing) it all should run on the tethered mobile connection.

With that setup I have the advantage to stream with the full potential of my home connection but yet still game flawlessly without a influence.

Is something like that possible and if so how do I do that ?

Best regards

Comment: How can you connect to these two internets? WiFi, Ethernet, USB?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I bridge a Verizon mobile hotspot modem/router to a Linksys router?](https://superuser.com/questions/384664/how-can-i-bridge-a-verizon-mobile-hotspot-modem-router-to-a-linksys-router)